# Concurrent receiveing/sending from/to one sender/receiver

Tags: c++, c, concurrency, mpi

I wonder if it is possible to concurrent receive the message from one sender, and other way round to concurrent sent to one receiver. And if yes how it will behave?

To make the question more clarified let imagine we have 4 threads, each of them is listening on message from the same source

```
MPI_Recv(buf, count, type, THE_SAME_SOURCE, tag, status)
```

All those threads are within the same MPI process, so all they have the same MPI rank. And from other MPI process or the same but from different thread, someone called MPI_Send. Does each of the receivers receive the same message, or just one of them, or some exception is thrown (error occured)?

And other way round, what if 4 threads (within the same MPI process or not) send message to the one receiver which may also be in the same MPI process or not. Does it receive all the messages?

I do not have big experience with MPI, and answer for above question may help me a lot.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Receives are processed in the order they are registered.  There is never an "at the same time" situation, since they are synchronised.

[Description of Point-To-Point Communication Semantics](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-11-html/node41.html#Node41)

So, in your first circumstance, this means that the one send that happens when four threads are waiting to receive will be sent to the first thread to have registered for receive, and the others will continue to wait for subsequent messages.

In your second circumstance, again there is no "at the same time".  The first thread to send the message will be the one that is received by the receive thread.  Other sends will not have receivers registered.

Comment: This is a great answer to the question.  +1 for the link.

Comment: Isn't this contrary to what the link says about multi-threaded execution? It states that "[...] Similarly, if two receive operations that are logically concurrent receive two successively sent messages, then the two messages can match the two receives in either order." The way I read it we can't know which thread's receive will "win". Am I wrong in this? Edit: Also my quote does say that two receive operations can indeed be logically concurrent (i.e., "at the same time").

Comment: @Quantumboredom: I can see how what the link says may be confusing.  The quote and the surrounding paragraph are pointing out that when you have two threads without any external sequence points, then you don't have any defined order that the sends and receives will occur in.  Sometimes you run and one will beat the other, and other times it may be the other way.  My point is that they are actually synchronised behind the scenes, so they never happen "at the same time".  In other words, my point is that there will always be a first and the behavior is defined by that order.

Comment: @Quantumboredom: About two receives, the distinction is between what is physically concurrent and what is logically concurrent.  The program may not define a specific order, because it may just let threads run and call whenever.  Translated to a multithreaded logic like the pi calculus, these would be called concurrent if they may happen together.  However, the actual calls, even if happening on different processors or cores, will have one acquire the transaction to receive first and be placed in the queue accordingly.  They may both be waiting together, but the behavior is always defined.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, this I do agree with :)